# Period usage when abbreviating at the end of a sentence

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, parentheses, periods

Regarding the following expression, we can realize that the period character is of dual functionality in its nature: partly denoting the abbreviation, partly being used to end the sentence.

> I like rideable animals such as donkeys, horsies, cowsies etc.

Now, if we reconstruct the sentence in the following way, we'll be forced to use separate period characters for each of the functions and it looks pretty weird, at least to me. I wonder if it's the correct usage at all and what a correct alternative might be.

> I like rideable animals (donkeys, horsies, cowsies etc.).

Please note that I'm **not in any way** asking about how to express the thought contained in the example nor that how to circumvent the situation (by rephrasing it as two different sentences or such).

Comment: Both example sentences are punctuated correctly. And do not look weird in the least. Also, what's this to do with grammar? This has nothing at all to do with grammar.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The combination period-parenthesis-period looks **very** weird to me. Am I in a vast minority on that? In such case, I have no further problems with that. As for the *grammar*, I thought it was about **grammatical** correctness, hence the choice of the tag. If you feel that there's a better one, please feel welcome to make use of the edit link. I'll be happy to improve my question by any means possible.

Comment: There are online resources that cover this. Try googling ***etc punctuation*** - here's an example http://www.editage.com/insights/research-paper-comma-after-etc-at-the-end-of-a-sentence

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I don't think the link is **exactly** relevant as it's not discussing the case with parenthesis between the periods. However, they give that as an example, without actually stating it explicitly (which can mean that it's **so** obviously correct but also that they just discuss something else).

Comment: I've added a couple tags. By the way, we might have actually discussed this in the past which would make this question a dupe. I'll search around when I have a spare minute.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Please do. I'm always keen on improving my google-fu and I haven't found **that particular** question (at least not asked **so explicitly**). The re-tagification's great, thanks for that.

Comment: Now everything's looking wrong to me :)  I'll try to find a better example?

Comment: I see there are several questions on this site already that address this. I will withdraw my answer, especially since I can't find my old style book -that I used to swear by.